# How grep count, with conditions

Tags: linux, grep

I have log file with this strings

```
2022-08-13 19:15:17.170 INFO 550034 --- [ scheduling-3] org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW : SlowQuery: 11387 milliseconds. SQL:
```

I need grep command to count slowQuery for last hour with time more than 10000 ms

I've try

```
grep "SQL_SLOW" app.log | wc -l
```

but i can't add two conditions:

1. time (first 19 symbols) must be between current time minus one hour
2. time for query must be more than 10000 ms (in example it 11387 ms)

Comment: How is it related to Kotlin?

Comment: log from application writing on Kotlin)

Comment: remove Kotlin from tags

Comment: Does it have to be grep? Which version of grep? BSD or GNU or something else? Does it have PCRE?

Comment: grep (GNU grep) 3.1
I don't know about PCRE

Comment: @BoLjshOJ : 10 seconds is already considered a slow query ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto it's for foglight metrics. We need to monitoring count of slow query. If the user waits more than 10 seconds to display information on the site it's not normal)

Answer (score 2):

`grep` is the wrong tool for the job; trying to get the date and time conditions to match via RE is just wrong.

How about `awk`?

```
echo '2022-08-13 19:15:17.170 INFO 550034 --- [ scheduling-3] org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW : SlowQuery: 11387 milliseconds. SQL:' \
| awk -v now=$(date "+%s") '
/SlowQuery:/ {
        tmp = "\" " $1 " " $2 "\""
        cmd = "date -d " tmp " +%s"
        cmd | getline ts
        t = gensub(/.*SlowQuery: ([0-9]+) milliseconds.*/, "\\1", "g", $0)
        if (now - ts < 3600 && t > 10000) {
                print $0
        }
}
```

Brief explanation: first we capture the current time in seconds since epoch.

Then we convert the timestamp for each line of the log containing `/SlowQuery:/` to seconds since epoch `tmp="\x22 "$1" "$2"\x22";cmd="date -d " tmp  " +%s";cmd|getline ts` and store it in the variable `ts`.

We extract the time taken `t=gensub(/.*SlowQuery: ([0-9]+) milliseconds.*/, "\\1", "g")` and store it in `t`.

The last step is to check if less than an hour has passed and the query was slower than 10000 ms `if(ts-now<3600 && t>10000){print $0}`. If both is true, print the line.

Comment: Great solution and everyone seems to need a one liner, but they're really hard to read on mobile devices. (I would further reformat with indenting to show the scructure, we'll leave that as an learning excercise for the O.P. (-;?) . Feel free to revert if you disagree. Cordially!

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me find this solution. But it have some admissions. Logs will not be exactly for the last hour, but for the current incomplete hour and for the previous hour (that is, depending on the current time, it will be from 1 to 2 hours)

```
grep "SQL_SLOW" "app.log" \
| grep "^$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H')" \
| grep -P "SlowQuery: \d{5,} milliseconds" \
| wc -l
```

But solution with awk looks like better